# MySQL bit inversion, how to only negate the fist x bits?

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation

I am using bitwise operators in MySQL. I have a column of 6 bits. When I used the bit negation operator "~" I get a 64 bt integer returned. This means I have a number of leading 1's that I don't want.

How do I negate only the last 6 bits (the rightmost 6 bits)?

Comment: your column is 6 bits, and you want to negate the last 6 bits? Isn't that basically just negating the whole column?

Comment: yes, but mysql is treating it as a 64 bit integer, so I get 58 leading 1's that I don't want.

Comment: `select ~foo & 0x3F`? bitwise not the field, then mask of all but the last 6 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XOR with one bits set for each bit you want to negate.

In your case, you would XOR by `0b00111111`, or `0x3F`.

Comment: `XOR` is a logical operator and has nothing to do with integer binary operations. In MySQL, `^` operator is a bitwise XOR